# How do I change my icon in the Hall of Fame?

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-5

When I completed the first campaign of *Heroes of Might and Magic V* I was taken to the Hall of Fame and was shown my place on there, in my case it was third.

However I seem to have an icon of a Vampire Lord, the same as second place Ihora and I'm not particularly fond of it. I looked in the Settings menu and the Profile selection and I can't seem to find an option to change this.

So how do I change my icon in the Hall of Fame?

NOTE: i'm playing version 1.6 using the H5_Game.exe in the bin folder (not the one in the bina folder which i assume is for the first expansion)

Answer (score 5):

Not sure how it works in HoMM V, but in previous versions of HoMM, the icon was directly related to your score.  To get a different icon, you had to get a higher (or lower) score.

Comment: Yep, this will be the answer.